# Why $ \sum_{k}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(n+1)^{k-1}}}n^k =n \cdot (n+1)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics

I found by chance that 
$$ 
f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(n+1)^{k-1}}}n^k
$$
seems to be equal to $n \cdot (n+1)$.
Proving this is out of my capabilities, but I would still love to see why that equivalence seems to hold.

So: is there a proof or intuitive explanation for why $f(n)=n \cdot (n+1)$?

Comment: where does the summation start? This is just a geometric series.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^{k-1}}n^k = (n+1)\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^k = (n+1)\left(\dfrac{1}{1-\tfrac{n}{n+1}}-1\right) = n(n+1)$$